# Android FFmpegMediaPlayer - MediaPlayer error(0, 0)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, stream, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm using this piece of code to play an *acc* that is on the cloud with **FFmpegMediaPlayer** taken from here:

https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer

Code:

```
FFmpegMediaPlayer player = new FFmpegMediaPlayer();
try {
  player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  player.setDataSource(url);
  player.prepareAsync();
} catch ( IOException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException e ){
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When the URL format is like "http://something.com/audio.aac" that code works fine.

But, when the URL is like "https://something.com/audio.aac?something_else_here" that code doesn't work and it fires en **Error(0,0)**.

Before **FFmpegMediaPlayer** I used the **MediaPlayer** with exact the same methods. Sometimes it had the same problems sometimes not, so I thought to switch to **FFmpegMediaPlayer** even because it is faster, but I'm not handling this error.

Does anyone now how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be several reasons why this error occurs but I'm going to show what  did I do in my case.
I thought that the problem was with the ending string of the link but it looks that it was OK.

I installed **FFmpegMediaPlayer** via gradle in my project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaPlayer:1.0.4'
}
```

but it looks that when I was calling

```
player.setDataSource(url);
player.prepareAsync();
```

it had a problem with `https` link.

So, what I did was to manually import the AAR package that supports the `HTTPS`. I downloaded it in:

https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer/releases/download/v1.0.3/prebuilt-aars-with-https.zip

There are several AAR files compiled for different architectures, but there is also an AAR file that includes all architectures.

So this, was the solution of my problem.

The drawback is that importing this AAR the size of your application will increase by 4MB at least or even by 20MB if you choose to include the file that is compiled for all architectures.

At the end I went on another approach, but definitely **Android** should take some care on its **MediaPlayer** because it gives so much pain to the developers.